# When finding all subsets of an array, result array returns empty subsets, any idea what's going on here?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to store all possible subsets of an array with recursion. When storing `subset` in my `result` array, I am getting an empty nested array. However, when I print `subset` within the base case, it appears. Anyone have an idea why `subset` is not appending to `result`.

Here's my code below:

```
def see_sequences(array):
    subset = list()
    result = list()
    hel(array, subset, 0, result)
    return result


def hel(arr, subset, i,result):
    if i == len(arr):
        result.append(subset)
        
    else:
        subset.append(None)
        hel(arr, subset,i+1, result)
        subset.pop()
        subset.append(arr[i])
        hel(arr,subset,i+1, result)
        subset.pop()
```

This is `result`

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

In main, I am running `see_sequences([1,2,3])`.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Lists only contain references to other objects. In your case multiple references to the same list. Solution: Make copy of subset with "subset[:]" and append that to "result".

Comment: Passing a mutable object to another function for mutation is just generally a bad idea in terms of code clarity. Why not pass a single result `tuple`, and add subset `tuple` objects to the result instead? Try to write pure functions, they're so much easier to debug.

Comment: In regards to what ddejohn said: especially in recursive cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested to know why all of your lists are empty.

```
subset.append(None)
hel(arr, subset,i+1, result)
subset.pop()
```

For each `append` there is a matching `pop`.  The pop occurs after the recursive call to `hel()`, where `subset` gets used like this:

```
if i == len(arr):
    result.append(subset)
```

Each time, you are appending *exactly the same list* to `result`.  The number of elements grows, but all the elements are exactly the same list.  They are not *copies* of the same list, let alone copies of the current state of the list - they are all literally the *same* object.

When the recursion finishes and the recursive calls unwind, the pop method removes every appended element.  At the end of the process the list is empty.  When your print statement executes, you are printing the same empty list 9 times.

I would also like to point out that your algorithm is not a real recursion at all, even though your function is making calls to itself.  You have actually written a simple `for` loop in a way that makes it look like recursion.  You initialize a loop index here:

```
hel(array, subset, 0, result)
```

because you set the third argument to 0.  You increment the loop index here:

```
hel(arr, subset,i+1, result)
```

when you add 1 to i.  You terminate the loop here:

```
if i == len(arr):
    result.append(subset)
```

by checking to see if you've reached the end of the list.

You pass all the variables you're working on down the stack of recursive calls.  What you have done is to hide the basic loop structure inside of all that code.

I don't know why you're trying to use recursion on this particular problem.  As far as I can see, recursion can't help you here.  If you're doing this as an exercise to learn a programming technique, this seems a poor choice.
If you really need this strange algorithm for a project you're working on, try doing it without recursion (ask a different question if you need help).